# retrieve row and column name of particular cell in R

Tags: r, dataframe

So if I have a data frame that looks like:

```
             A     B      C  
  rowname1   4.5   4      3.2
  rowname2   3     23     9
```

How do I get R to give me the name(s) of the row/columns that contain a particular number?

i.e. if I give the value 3, it gives back

```
 rowname2,A
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it return "rowname1,C" instead?  That value is also 3...

Comment: It's now 3.2 ... I didnt mean to have duplicates, just rushed it

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it's _impossible_ for your actual data to have duplicates?

Comment: with duplicates you could use `melt` from `reshape2` and return all rows.  If your data is named `df`: `library(reshape2); df.m <- melt(df); df[df$value==3,]`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming no duplicates, you can use `which` combined with the `arr.ind` argument:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100,12), ncol=3))
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1  84 58 36
# 2   9 40 92
# 3 100 28 78
# 4  15 98 29

index <- which(df==36, arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   1   3
```

If you must have the actual row and column names of the location, then just index into them appropriately:

```
paste(rownames(df)[index[1]], colnames(df)[index[2]], sep=", ")
# [1] "1, X3"
```

Comment: Your code works just fine if there are dupes.  It will list all ordered pairs of coordinates.  Now, should we warn pepsimax about the difference between `==`  and `all.equal` ?

Comment: while you're correct to think that I don't know the difference between them, this code works perfect so I'm happy for now. thanks guys!

Comment: If you do not know the difference, you will be doomed to repeat the many failures of past persons who _thought_ they understood computer math. I hereby curse you to unexpected and unpredictable failures until you remove the curse by doing the necessary study of those two functions and read the FAQ.

Comment: I'm trying to learn R by teaching myself as my first programming language. I'm not expecting to learn it easily...

Comment: Then you definitely need to read the FAQ and "The R-Inferno" .  I only wish I could warn you in as creative prose as DWin did.  http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/all.html  has a very good, detailed manual.

Answer (score 4):

May be writing a simple function could help you out:

```
Which.names <- function(DF, value){
   ind <- which(DF==value, arr.ind=TRUE)
   paste(rownames(DF)[ind[1:nrow(ind)]],  colnames(DF)[ind[2]], sep=', ')
}

  DF <- read.table(text="A     B      C  
  rowname1   4.5   4      3.2
  rowname2   3     23     9", header=TRUE)

  Which.names(DF, value=3)
[1] "rowname2, A"

  Which.names(DF, value=4.5)
[1] "rowname1, A"

  Which.names(DF, value=9.0)
[1] "rowname2, C"
```

It also allows you to work with duplicated values.

```
 DF[1,1] <-3.0 
 Which.names(DF, value=3)
[1] "rowname1, B" "rowname2, B" 

 DF[1,2] <- 3
 Which.names(DF, value=3)
[1] "rowname1, B" "rowname2, B" "rowname1, B"
```

Comment: I've just edit my answer so that can allow you to work with duplicate values.

Answer (score -1):

there's some problems in the code in Jilber's answer, need to change a little bit, should be like this (R version 3.1.2):

## both works (notice the difference between the initial letters of these two functions, "W" & "w")

## 1st

```
Which.names <- function(DF, value){
   ind <- which(DF==value, arr.ind=TRUE)
   for (i in 1:nrow(ind)) print(paste(rownames(DF)[ind[i,"row"]],  colnames(DF)[ind[i,"col"]], sep=', '))
}
```

## 2nd (the better one)

```
which.names <- function(DF, value){
   ind <- which(DF==value, arr.ind=TRUE)
   print(paste(rownames(DF)[ind[,"row"]],  colnames(DF)[ind[,"col"]], sep=', '))
}
```

## result here below

```
> DF <- read.table(text="A     B      C  
+   rowname1   4.5   4      3.2
+   rowname2   3     23     9", header=TRUE)
> DF
           A  B   C
rowname1 4.5  4 3.2
rowname2 3.0 23 9.0
> Which.names(DF,3)
[1] "rowname2, A"
> which.names(DF,3)
[1] "rowname2, A"
> Which.names(DF,4)
[1] "rowname1, B"
> which.names(DF,4)
[1] "rowname1, B"
> Which.names(DF,9)
[1] "rowname2, C"
> which.names(DF,9)
[1] "rowname2, C"
> DF[1,1] <-3.0
> DF
         A  B   C
rowname1 3  4 3.2
rowname2 3 23 9.0
> Which.names(DF,3)
[1] "rowname1, A"
[1] "rowname2, A"
> which.names(DF,3)
[1] "rowname1, A" "rowname2, A"
> DF[1,2] <- 3
> DF
         A  B   C
rowname1 3  3 3.2
rowname2 3 23 9.0
> Which.names(DF,3)
[1] "rowname1, A"
[1] "rowname2, A"
[1] "rowname1, B"
> which.names(DF,3)
[1] "rowname1, A" "rowname2, A" "rowname1, B"
```