# Get column and row names of matrix indices in a vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a 4x4 matrix and I want to identify elements of this matrix that are equal to a specific value such as 1. I want to save the indices of these elements as well as column and row names to two separate vectors. Finally, I want to write all of this information to a txt file.

I managed to get the indices to a txt file but I have no idea how to retrieve the column and row names from the matrix. To test, I am using following example:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol=4, nrow=4)
colnames(mat) <- c("C1","C2","C3","C4")
rownames(mat) <- c("R1", "R2","R3","R4")

r.indices <- c()
c.indices <- c()
for (row in 1:nrow(mat)){
    for (col in 1:(ncol(mat)-row+1)){

        if (mat[row,col] == cutoff){
            #print("this is one!")
            r.indices <- c(r.indices,row)
            c.indices <- c(c.indices,col)
        }

     }
}


write.csv(cbind(r.indices, c.indices), file="data.txt")
```

Comment: Searching with your favorite web search engine would have lead to [retrieve row and column name of particular cell in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464731/retrieve-row-and-column-name-of-particular-cell-in-r).

Comment: searching with my favourite web search engine lead here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `which` function already provides a nice interface to getting all the row and column indices of a matrix that meet a certain criterion, using the `arr.ind=TRUE` argument. This is both much less typing and much more efficient than looping through each matrix element. For instance, if you wanted to get all the indices where your matrix equaled 5, you could use:

```
(idx <- which(mat == 5, arr.ind=TRUE))
#    row col
# R1   1   2
# R3   3   4
```

Now all that remains is a simple lookup using the row and column names of your matrix:

```
cbind(rownames(mat)[idx[,"row"]], colnames(mat)[idx[,"col"]])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "R1" "C2"
# [2,] "R3" "C4"
```

You could write this result out to a file using `write.csv`.

Comment: you rock! thanks a lot. how about loading huge RData files? do you have any suggestions for the cases where lazyload does not work either?

Comment: @wthimdh Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with loading huge RData files. I would suggest that you ask a separate question on this topic so the whole R community can see it and respond.

Comment: what if I want to keep only nonzero elements (but it is not really a sparse matrix) of a matrix with indices in a txt file. Such as col row and value in each line. Can I something  like idx <- which(mat != 5, arr.ind=TRUE) for that? Or do i have to use a for loop?

Comment: @wthimdh You can just use `write.table` or `write.csv` to write the output of the commands I've shown here to a file.