# How do I find the row and column number for a particular string in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the following data.table:

```
DT <- setDT(data.frame(id = 1:10, LETTERS = LETTERS[1:10], 
            letters = letters[1:10]))


##+ > DT
##     id LETTERS letters
##  1:  1       A       a
##  2:  2       B       b
##  3:  3       C       c
##  4:  4       D       d
##  5:  5       E       e
##  6:  6       F       f
##  7:  7       G       g
##  8:  8       H       h
##  9:  9       I       i
## 10: 10       J       j
```

and I want to find the row and column numbers of the letter 'h' (which are 8 and 3). How would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464731/retrieve-row-and-column-name-of-particular-cell-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DT[, which(.SD == "h", arr.ind = TRUE)]

#      row col
# [1,]   8   3
```

*EDIT:*

Trying to take into account Michael's points:

```
str_idx = which(sapply(DT, function(x) is.character(x) || is.factor(x)))
idx <- DT[, which(as.matrix(.SD) == "h", arr.ind = TRUE), .SDcols = str_idx]
idx[, "col"] <- chmatch(names(str_idx)[idx[, "col"]], names(DT))
idx 

#     row col
# [1,]   8   3
```

Comment: this works and is elegant! but inadvisable for huge tables due to matrix conversion. An easy improvement would be subsetting `.SD` to only include string columns... but as `data.frame` is fundamentally different data type from matrix, there will still be conversion cost. Faster _may_ be to use `which(as.matrix(.SD), ...)`; I'm not sure at a glance if which will use the slightly-optimized `as.matrix.data.table` method

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the exact format of your desired output.

```
# applying to non-string columns is inefficient
str_idx = which(sapply(DT, is.character))

# returns a list as long as str_idx with two elements appropriately named
lapply(str_idx, function(jj) list(row = which(DT[[jj]] == 'h'), col = jj))
```

It should also be possible to `melt` the string columns your table to avoid looping.